# Trying to Compare an Integer input by user to a text file and outputting Certain lines from that txt file

Tags: python, parsing, text-files

I am trying to create a function that takes in a number and compares it to that same number in a txt file. If there is a number, output that entire line, else output that there is no number. Currently, there are only 9 lines.

My txt file (called nbaPointsLeaders.txt) is as follows

```
    1. James Harden, Houston Rockets, 30.4
    2. Anthony Davis ,New Orleans Pelicans, 28.1
    3. LeBron James, Cleveland Cavaliers, 27.5
    4. Damian Lillard, Portland Trail Blazers, 26.9
    5. Giannis Antetokounmpo, Milwaukee Bucks, 26.8
    6. Kevin Durant, Golden State Warriors, 26.4
    7. Russell Westbrook, Oklahoma City Thunder, 25.4
    8. Kyrie Irving, Boston Celtics, 24.4
    9. LaMarcus Aldridge, San Antonio Spurs, 23.1
```

If the user inputs 1, input the entire first line.

Another problem I am running into is:

```
    TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
```

and this comes up whenever I ask a user to input a number.

This is the code I have come up with so far. I am a beginner at python so it might be something obvious too.

```
    def leaderInPoints(number):
        number = int(input("What number from 1-9 would you like to see?"))
        with open('nbaPointsLeader.txt','r') as file:
              return [i for i in f if number in i])
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried ?

Comment: Just updated the question with what I have so far.

Comment: What is variable `f`?

Comment: f is the file. Guess i forgot to update that in my return statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def leaderInPoints(number):

    number = int(input("What number from 1-9 would you like to see?"))
    file = open('nbaPointsLeader.txt','r')
    # get all lines
    content = file.readlines()
    # we get the nth line
    return content[number]
```

Comment: so I get this error when I tried to implement that:

        ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

Comment: I updated my code it seems that your file has float values so you have to change int to float

Comment: So this time, the error that I'm getting has to do with converting a string to a float

When I ran the function, it gave me this error on the following line:

if float(line[2]) == number:


        ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: Okay I fixed it can you please try now ?

Comment: It compiled, but the output was just an empty list 

Compiler:

What number from 1-9 would you like to see? 5
[]

Comment: It's normal because the file doesn't have any line with value 5 . Type 30.4 and it will display

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. However, it's the value 5 that I want the entire line to display. Sorry if that wasn't clear. The first number in each line goes from 1-9. So if the user types 5, have the 5th line display

Comment: I have updated my code. You can now type the line number instead.

Comment: Worked this time! Thanks so much for all the help!

Comment: One question that I have though is how does content[int(number)] compare the number a user input to the same number in the line and output the entire line?

Comment: content is an array that contains the list of all the lines so each line has its own index, ranging from 0 to the last line number. content[number] retrieves the number at the specified index and prints it. I just updated the code as you no longer need to convert to float